# Custom empty cells in UITabelView

Tags: ios, uitableview

i got ios application with `UITableView`

I customize cells in this table, but when number of objects lower than visible cells on screen, all other cells look like simple UITableViewCells.

[image]

It should look like this

[image]

How should i customize all cells?

**UPD** Code for dataSource:

```
pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [dataBase.showMaps count];

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 70;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ShowMapCell *cell = (ShowMapCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ShowMapCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    ShowMap *sM = [dataBase.showMaps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //cell.textLabel.text = sM.name;

    [cell initShowMapCell:sM index:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: put relavent code here :)

Comment: Please post your code, specifically your datasource and delegate methods for UITableView.

Comment: @iPatel you can see my code in upd.

Comment: @Tim you can see my code in upd

Comment: im having a hard time understanding your question. as i understand it, theres not enough content to fill your entire table view. how do you expect it to look like it has benn filled then? those "empty cells" arent cells so much as just placeholders for cells that could be created if you had more content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have just set background color of the tableview. However that solution wont work because you are using different backgrounds for each cell.

So according to me to achieve what you want you need to add some extra (blank) rows to the table and for that you need to return your record + extra cell `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method. And above that you need to set the background color of table view to one of the cell background because if you are using bouncing effect in the tableview you will find white color when you scroll the tableview up/down.

Comment: Yes, this is not a full-proof and efficient solution, however in this case it will work like a charm. Glad it is of help to you. :)

Comment: plus this workaround requires you to check the size of the phone to calculate the number of rows to be displayed. Plus, if there's a little bit of a cell showing up at the bottom, you cannot do anything about it: if you add +1 row to be able to customize it, you enable scrolling (which makes no sense on a "supposedly empty" tableview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your UITableView not to have 'empty cells', you will need to hide the cell separators and change the background colour of the tableview to match your colour scheme.

As katzenhut said in the comments, they aren't cells, they are placeholders for content.  So if you hide the separators and add them in the xib file for your UITableViewCell ShowCell, then they will no longer be seen when there isn't a cell to place in the table.